# How to display reporting services record set in a collection of textboxes

Tags: reporting-services

I have a recordset that contains only 1 record but I need to display the result (10 fields)
in 2 columns with matching label

the textbox doesn't have a datasetname property.

how can i display 10 fields in 2 columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

right click the textbox
select expressions
select dataset
select your dataset
select First([fieldname])

voila